# Return to original request after refresh token

Tags: axios, vuejs3, pinia

I make certain requests via Axios via a pinia store.
These requests are via a timer, multiple requests can be sent.
My server works with tokens that need to be refreshed.
I have written an interceptor that checks the expiration time of the access token and sends a refresh token before it is invalid.
All requests that happen while I handle the refresh token are stored in an array.
Now this works, but I do not return to where the request was made (pinia store), so the data is not adjusted.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {useAuthStore} from "@/stores/Authentication/AppAuthStore.js";
import VueJwtDecode from 'vue-jwt-decode';


axios.defaults.baseURL = import.meta.env.VITE_API_ENDPOINT;
axios.defaults.maxRedirects = 0;
let refreshing_token = null;
let myTimeout= null;
let busy = false;
let requestArray = [];
const baseURL = import.meta.env.VITE_API_ENDPOINT;


axios.interceptors.request.use( async req =>{
    if (req.url.endsWith("refresh")) {
        // if we are making a refresh token call, return it to prevent infinite loop
        return req;
    }

    const accesstoken = sessionStorage.getItem("accesstoken")
    if (accesstoken){
        req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accesstoken}`;
        //const {header,payload} = useJwt(accesstoken)
        let user = VueJwtDecode.decode(accesstoken);
        const isExpired = Date.now() >= ((user.exp * 1000) - 10000)
        console.log(isExpired)
        if (!isExpired) return req;
        requestArray.push(req);
        console.log("is expired");
/*        refreshing_token = refreshing_token ? refreshing_token : refresh_token();
        let res  = await refreshing_token;
        refreshing_token = null;
        clearTimeout(myTimeout);*/
        if (!busy){
            busy = true;
            const refreshtoken = sessionStorage.getItem("refreshtoken")
            axios.post(baseURL + 'auth/refresh', {
                refresh_token : refreshtoken
            }).then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                console.log("token refreshed : " + res.data.accesstoken);
                const authappstore = useAuthStore()
                authappstore.isAppOK = true;
                sessionStorage.setItem("accesstoken",res.data.accesstoken);
                sessionStorage.setItem("refreshtoken", res.data.refreshtoken);
                req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${res.data.accesstoken}`;
                if (requestArray.length !== 0) {
                    requestArray.forEach(x => {
                        try {
                            console.log(x);
                            axios(x)
                        } catch (e) {
                            console.log(e)
                        }
                    });
                    requestArray = [];

                }
            }) .catch((err) => {
                const errStatus = err.statusCode || 500;
                const errMsg = err.message || 'Something went wrong';
                console.log(errMsg)
            }) .finally(() => {
                busy = false;
            });
        }


    }
    else {
        return req
    }
    


})

export default axios;
```

I have no idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just provide an idea ,you need to wait for a new access token When a request's access token expired, and go on that request (not push them to an array), so we need to return a Promise in the request interceptors to make the request in a waiting status,  and we need create a CustomEvent ,when the request of getRefreshToken completed ,the CustomEvent triggered,  the Promise will be resolved at this time, and the request will go on.

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  useAuthStore
} from "@/stores/Authentication/AppAuthStore.js";
import VueJwtDecode from 'vue-jwt-decode';

axios.defaults.baseURL =
  import.meta.env.VITE_API_ENDPOINT;
axios.defaults.maxRedirects = 0;
let refreshing_token = null;
let myTimeout = null;
let busy = false;
const baseURL =
  import.meta.env.VITE_API_ENDPOINT;
const getRefreshToken = new CustomEvent('getRefreshToken');
axios.interceptors.request.use(async req => {
  if (req.url.endsWith("refresh")) {
    // if we are making a refresh token call, return it to prevent infinite loop
    return req;
  }
  const accesstoken = sessionStorage.getItem("accesstoken")
  if (accesstoken) {
    req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accesstoken}`;
    //const {header,payload} = useJwt(accesstoken)
    let user = VueJwtDecode.decode(accesstoken);
    const isExpired = Date.now() >= ((user.exp * 1000) - 10000)
    console.log(isExpired)
    if (!isExpired) return req;
    return refresh(req)
  } else {
    return req
  }
})

function refresh(req) {
  if (!busy) {
    busy = true;
    const refreshtoken = sessionStorage.getItem("refreshtoken")
    axios.post(baseURL + 'auth/refresh', {
      refresh_token: refreshtoken
    }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      console.log("token refreshed : " + res.data.accesstoken);
      const authappstore = useAuthStore()
      authappstore.isAppOK = true;
      sessionStorage.setItem("accesstoken", res.data.accesstoken);
      sessionStorage.setItem("refreshtoken", res.data.refreshtoken);
      window.dispatchEvent(getRefreshToken)
    }).catch((err) => {
      const errStatus = err.statusCode || 500;
      const errMsg = err.message || 'Something went wrong';
      console.log(errMsg)
    }).finally(() => {
      busy = false;
    });
  }
  return new Promise(res => {
    function send() {
      const accesstoken = sessionStorage.getItem("accesstoken");
      req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accesstoken}`;
      res(req)
      window.removeEventListener('getRefreshToken', send)
    }
    window.addEventListener('getRefreshToken', send)
  })
}
```